# Message parameters are not substituted to the actual placeholders in a message stored in a property file while using RegexFieldValidator in Struts2

Tags: java, regex, struts2

I'm using `@RegexFieldValidator` on a method as follows.

```
@Validations(
        regexFields={
            @RegexFieldValidator(caseSensitive=false, fieldName="colourHex", regex="[0-9, a-f, A-F]+", key="colour.hex.pattern", messageParams={"A", "F"})})
@Action(value = "AddColour",
    results = {@Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", location="Colour.jsp", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Colour", "currentPage", "${currentPage}", "editId", "${editId}"}),
    @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Colour.jsp")},
    interceptorRefs={@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "editId, colourId, colourName, colourHex, currentPage, rowCount, totalPages", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})})
public String insert() {
    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

The message which the given key refers to is kept in a property file like the following.

> colour.hex.pattern=Only digits and letters from {0} to {1} either
>   capital or small are significant.

The placeholders are not replaced by the given parameters. They are `null` and consequently, the message formed is,

> Only digits and letters from null to null either capital or small are
>   significant.

It should actually be like as follows.

> Only digits and letters from A to F either capital or small are
>   significant.

Why aren't the parameters substituted to the placeholders?

<sub>Validation is performed correctly according to the given pattern.</sub>

Comment: Unrelated, but why use placeholders in this case?

Comment: In this case yes, placeholders are not needed, since the hex code are fixed from `A` to `F` (include digits from 0 to 9) but I just thought that a need might arise in future for other kind of validations.

Comment: Can you post how do you assign message to placeholder? As far I can recall, S2 doesn't support that without additional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `messageParams` are evaluated against the value stack so your `A` and `F` are evaluated and returns nulls. You need to pass them as strings e.g. `"\"A\""`.

```
@Validations(
        regexFields={
            @RegexFieldValidator(caseSensitive=false, fieldName="colourHex",
            regex="[0-9, a-f, A-F]+", key="colour.hex.pattern",
            messageParams={"\"A\"", "\"F\""})})
```

Comment: Evaluated in the sense, *OGNL expressions*? I already faced this situation at a different spot but I simply avoided it. Thanks.